# Como fazer gráfico com triângulos?

Tags: c#, mschart

Bom vou tentar ser bem explicativo: eu gostaria de saber se existe possibilidade de usar o chart e fazer triângulos nele passando as 3 coordenadas para gerar os triângulos, como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
(Não liguem pela imagem eu fiz só um esquema ilustrativo no paint rapidão aqui)

Bom se existir possibilidade, e alguém poder me passar algum material ou exemplo de como fazer eu agradeço.

Comment: Vê se te ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/a/13291095/3257568